# How do you test keyboard accessibility with prototyping software?

Tags: accessibility, usability-testing

How does one test keyboard driven navigation using only prototyping software? I currently use sketch + invision for prototyping, is there a plugin or a better option?

Im aware that the best option would be creating a html page , but I dont have the resources to do that right now.

Comment: Not sure that you can really test it properly, but I know that many prototyping software provide triggers for interactions which you can encode as mouse clicks or keyboard key combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You should try **Adobe Xd** if you want to add keyboard triggers in your prototype. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/in/xd/help/keys-gamepad-triggers.html